# triangle numbers in java

Tags: java, numbers

I am new to Java and now I want to learn better for loop. I made some examples , but I don't know how to do a triangle that look like this:
 for n=6:

```
111111 
22222
3333
444
55
6
```

My code until now:

```
class Pyramid
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
   int i,n=9,j; 
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
       for(j=1;j<=i;j++)  {          
System.out.print(i); }      
System.out.print("\n");        
}}}
```

But what I managed to do it looks like this:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
666666
```

How to make it in reverse order ?

Comment: I suggest learning how a for loop works, not by example, but by how it is defined, and learn its concepts. Simply following examples blindly(as seen here) won't help in the future.

Comment: Your desired output is 1-2-3-2-1-6. I don't see the pattern. What would it look like for n=5 or n=7?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, you're ritgh. for n=7, the output should be: 1111111 / 222222 / 33333/4444 /555 / 66  and 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use is a function `int numberForRow(int row)` that will perform a suitable transformation. Then the function can be used like `r = numberForRow(i); print(r)`. It needs to map this:

```
row (i) -> display number (r)
6          1
5          2
4          3
3          4
2          5
1          6
```

I think you can write it :)

Look at the relationship between the input (i) and output (r) - it might be useful to note that they always add up to the same value so a little bit of math should do the trick.

(While a function isn't strictly required I find that such functions can help break down a problem and, especially in this case, illustrate a transformation well - it also works in case of a "more advanced" transformation, such as was in the original question ;-)

Comment: I accepted your question because you made me trying harder to understand the code and I managed to do it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @alexAlex Thanks, I entirely missed the height inversion though. Have fun programming and keep at it :)

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is that your outer `for` loop was going from `6` to `1`, so you need to reverse that.

Change

```
for(i=n;i>=1;i--) {
```

To

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
```

Further explanation, so you understand what is happening inside a `for` loop:

A `for` loop operates on three clauses: where you start, the condition that the loop runs, and what to do after it runs.

```
------v
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
```

This is the assignment. You set a variable to a number, which is where the loop starts. In this case, we start with `i = 1`, since we want to print only one `1` on the first line. In the third clause, we will increment it (read: add one to it), and run the loop again.

```
--------------v
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
```

This is the condition. The loop will run whenever this condition evaluates to `true`. In other words, if `n = 6`, this loop will run when `i <= 6`.

```
--------------------v
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
```

This is what will happen each time the loop is executed. After it runs through once when `i = 1`, we will increment `i`, so now `i = 2`. This will happen until the condition (`i <= n`) evaluates to `false`, i.e. when `i = 7`. If the condition is `false`, the loop will terminate.

Comment: Thank you, but even if it starts from number 1 as I want, I need number 1 to be printed 6 times, then number 2 five times..

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think it is the desired output

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Pyramid {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int i,n=9,j; 
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            //for(j=1;j<=i;j++)  { 
            for(j=n;j>=i;j--) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }      
            System.out.print("\n");        
        }
    }
}
```

This should help.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done using below method:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = 6;
        int m =n;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++,m--) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
                System.out.print(i);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the triangular numbers then use the following code

```
`public class Triangular{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    int j =0;
    int count =0;
    for (i=1;i<=10;i++){
        count = 0;  // This is a program to print triangular numbers in JAVA
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
            count = count + j;
        }
            System.out.println(count);
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: I think the code is self explanatory for a coder searching for something like this. I would like if the user can solve it in one loop rather than two and decrease its complexity. I have a solution to it.